# Best way to manage internationalization in database

Tags: node.js, database, internationalization, sequelize.js

I ' ve some troubles , managing my i18n in my database

For now I ' just two languages available on my application , but in order to be scalable, I would like to do it the "best" way.

I could have duplicated all fields like `description_fr, description_en` but I was no confortable with this at all. What I've done for now, is a external table , call it `content`, and its architecture is like this :

```
id_ref => entity referenced id (2)
type => table name (university)
field => field of the specific table (description)
lang => which lang (fr, en, es…)
content => and finally the appropriate content.
```

I think it can be important to precise, I use sequelizeJS as ORM. So I can use a usefull hooks as afterFind, afterCreate and afterUpdate. So Each time I wanna to find a resource for example, after find it, my hook retrieve all content for this resource and set definitly my object with goods values. It works, but I'm not in love with this.

But I have some troubles with this :

- It's increase considerably my number of requests to the database : If I select 50 rows for example, I have to do 50 requests more.. , and just for a particular model. If I have nested models, it's exponential…
- Then, It's complicated to fetch data by content i18ned. Example find a university with a specific name is complicated.
- And It's a lot of work for updating etc...

So I wonder, if it would be a good idea , to save as a JSON, directly in the table concerned , the data. Something like

```
{
    fr : { 'name':'Ma super université' },
    en : { 'name':'My kick ass university' }
}
```

And keep on using Sequelize Hooks to build and insert proper data into my object.

What do you think ? 
How do you manage this ?

---

**EDIT**

- I use a mysql database
- It concerns around 20 fields (cross models)
- I have to set the default value using a my default_lang if there is no content set (e.g, event.description in french will be the same as the english one, if there is no content set)

Comment: Just I wonder that why you want to store the static i18n data in your database? Because generaly i18n data needs to change when changing the source.

Answer (score 1):

I used this npm package [sequelize-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-i18n). It worked pretty fine for me using sequelize 3.23.2, unfortunately it seems does not have support for sequelize 4.x yet.